# Creating a method that I can call in the main method

Tags: c#, methods

Instruction: DoublePrompt() - Prints some prompt text to the console, reads in user response and returns that value as a parsed double.  This method should protect against invalid numeric entries. When the user enters an invalid input, it should prompt them to enter a valid numeric input over and over again.

This is the code in my main method:

```
        while (choice.ToUpper() == "Y" )
        {
            double length = DoublePrompt`("\nPlease enter package length: ");
            double width = DoublePrompt("Please enter package width: ");
            double height = DoublePrompt("Please enter package height: ");
            double weight = DoublePrompt("Please enter package weight: ");

            double cost = CalculatePackageCost(length, width, height, weight); totalCost += cost;
            PrintCost("package", cost); choice = PackagePrompt();
        }
        while (choice.ToUpper() == "Y" )
        {
            double length = DoublePrompt`("\nPlease enter package length:");
            double width = DoublePrompt("Please enter package width: ");
            double height = DoublePrompt("Please enter package height: ");
            double weight = DoublePrompt("Please enter package weight: ");

            double cost = CalculatePackageCost(length, width, height, weight); totalCost += cost;
            PrintCost("package", cost); choice = PackagePrompt();
        }
```

How do I create a method that does what the instruction states? 
This is all that I have so far:

```
static double DoublePrompt(string Measurements )
    {
        string choice = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine());


    }
```

Any assistance will be appreciated

Comment: Your static `Main()` method is in some class.  The easiest thing to do is to add your `DoublePrompt()` static method to the same class :)  Make sure to have "DoublePrompt()" actually return a double ;)

Comment: (A) Look up the documentation and read **carefully** about what `double.TryParse` does and how to use it. (B) Why do you try assigning the result (rerturn value) of `double.TryParse` to a **string** variable?

Comment: break down your problem into parts:
(A) Prints some prompt text to the console.
(B) Read in use input
(C) return that value(from (b)) as a parsed double
(D) protect against invalid numeric entries- this is a bit ambiguous,  protect how, decline the entry, throw an exception, what?
all the other ((A), (B), and (C) ) can be found easily with google

Comment: Specify what should happen when an invalid numeric value is entered.

Comment: Well, following your last edit, I think my answer should cover everything but writing the code for you. I suggest you give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's review the instructions:

> DoublePrompt() - Prints some prompt text to the console, reads in user response and returns that value as a parsed double. This method should protect against invalid numeric entries.

So The first thing this method should do is `Console.WriteLine` - to print the prompt text to the console. Then, it should read the user's response (using `Console.ReadLine()`), try to parse it as double (using the `double.TryParse()` method), and return the double back to the caller.

What should happen if the user enters some random string that can't be parsed to double?
The instruction doesn't say, but let's think about it for a second: from the application point of view, there's no point of moving on since we are missing a value the user should have entered. from the user's point of view, they might have tried typing something like `6.35` and accidentally pressed `t` with the `5` and got `6.35t` - which will fail the `double.TryParse` - so as a user, you would like to be notified your input is invalid and get a chance to reenter it.

So your method should do something like this:

1. Take in a string parameter.
2. Inside a loop, write the parameter to the console, and get the user response.
3. try to parse the user response to a double, if success, return the double. if fail, prompt a message to the customer saying the input can't be parsed to double, and start the loop again.

Since this is clearly a homework assignment I'll let you do the coding yourself, because otherwise you will learn nothing from my answer.
I will, however, leave you with one last hint - you can use a `do {}while(condition)` loop or use `while(true)` and `return` inside.